# Minimum and Maximum query not working properly (Python 3.5)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wonder if you can help because I've been looking at this for a good half hour and I'm completely baffled, I think I must be missing something so I hope you can shed some light on this.

In this area of my program I am coding a query which will search a list of tuples for the salary of the person. Each tuple in the list is a separate record of a persons details, hence I have used two indexes; one for the record which is looped over, and one for the salary of the employee. What I am aiming for is for the program to ask you a minimum and maximum salary and for the program to print the names of the employees who are in that salary range.

It all seemed to work fine, until I realised that when entering in the value '100000' as a maximum value the query would output nothing. Completely baffled I tried entering in '999999' which then worked and all records were print. The only thing that I can think of is that the program is ignoring the extra digit, which I could not figure out why this would be?!

Below is my code for that specific section and output for a maximum value of 999999 (I would prefer not to paste the whole program as this is for a coursework project and I want to prevent anyone on the same course potentially copying my work, sorry if this makes my question unclear!):

**The maximum salary out of all the records is 55000, hence why it doesnt make sense that a minimum of 0 and maximum of 100000 does not work, but a maximum of 999999 does!**

If any more information is need to help, please ask! This probably seems unclear but like I said above, I dont want anyone from the class to plagiarise and my work to be void because of that! So I have tried to ask this without posting all my code on here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your use of the `print` function (instead of the Python 2 `print` statement), it looks like you're writing Python 3 code. In Python 3, [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) returns a `str`. I'm guessing your data is also storing the salaries as `str` (otherwise the comparison would raise a `TypeError`). You need to convert both stored values and the result of `input` to `int` so it performs numerical comparisons, not ASCIIbetical comparisons.

Comment: Thanks! I completely see what you are saying is right, however I'm a little bit unsure as to how I convert the stored values to integers because the coursework requires that I import the records from a .txt file, so they come as str types and I'm not sure how I change this!

Comment: I converted the user input easily by changing it to `int(input(" "))` so that doesnt need to be worried about

Comment: @RJB: In the code that parses the `.txt` file, you need to ensure it's converting the relevant values to `int`. For example, if the file is just space separated text, you might do `record = line.split()`, `record[2] = int(record[2])`, `tuplist.append(tuple(record))`

Comment: Sorry to be a bother, I have tried doing this but I have a problem in which that I use the ".join" method which doesnt work when the string has an int inside of it, I'm a little bit lost to as where I go now

Comment: @RJB: Convert back to an iterable of `str` when stringifying, or use a format string. `' '.join(map(str, record))` or (assuming three elements in a record) `'{} {} {}'.format(*record)`.

Answer (score 1):

When you read in from standard input in Python, no matter what input you get, you receive the input as a string. That means that your comparison function is resulting to:

```
if tuplist[x][2] > "0" and tuplist[x][2] < "999999" :
```

Can you see what the problem is now? Because it's a homework assignment, I don't want to give you the answer straight away.